# Check if the parent contains hash tag-Cross domain

Tags: java, javascript

Hi is it possible to check if the parent URL contains hash tag without getting "Permission Denied". The checking occurs in child frame-different domain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Without cooperating domains using cross-domain messaging, you cannot reach from one domain into a different frame from a different domain and look at it's URL or hash tag.

You can see the description of same-origin restrictions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

If the two frames (on different domains) were cooperating, you could use `window.postMessage()` to communicate between the two in modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the info.I just want to use it to hack the browser history but since they are in the different domain I got Permission denied. Do you have any way around to hack browser history using child frame? Thanks.

Comment: @gerboy - If the two domains cooperate (code in both frames to accomplish a task), you can do it.  But, if you don't control the code in the other frame, then there is no way to do it.  That's what same-origin restrictions are for - to keep your code from mucking with some other domain's page.  A browser plug-in could do this (it isn't subject to same-origin restrictions), but of course the plug-in would have to be installed before it would work.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00. I got another possible solution to my problem but I want to consult it first. The "history.pushState()".do you think it will solve the "Permission Denied" or the same origin restriction? Thanks :)

Comment: @gerboy - I really do not understand exactly what you're trying to do.  Perhaps if you edit your question to describe more specifically exactly what you're trying to do, someone might have an idea for you.